# SQL Server Insert "The multi-part identifier could not be bound"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm coming from Oracle and have a few problems with SQL Server Management Studio.

We have a View but it's horrible slow and takes around 50 seconds. So I would like to create a static table and insert the result of the view into this table by a trigger or with a daily batch job.

The view looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers]
AS
    WITH ProductList AS
    (
        SELECT  
            p.Serialnumber, p.Type_Id,
            p.Date, p.Parent_Serialnumber, 
            p.ActiveJob_Jobnumber as JobNumber,
            N'/' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.Serialnumber)) + N'/' AS ProductNode_AsChar
        FROM 
            Products AS p
        WHERE 
            p.Parent_Serialnumber IS NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
            p.Serialnumber, p.Type_Id,
            p.Date, p.Parent_Serialnumber, 
            JobNumber,
            pl.ProductNode_AsChar + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.Serialnumber)) + N'/'
        FROM 
            Products AS p
        INNER JOIN 
            ProductList AS pl ON p.Parent_Serialnumber = pl.Serialnumber
    ) 
    SELECT  
        Serialnumber, pt.Name as TypeName,
        Date, Parent_Serialnumber,
        JobNumber,
        CONVERT(HIERARCHYID, ProductNode_AsChar) AS ProductNode
    FROM 
        ProductList AS pl
    INNER JOIN 
        ProductTypes AS pt ON pl.Type_Id = pt.Id;
```

I've created a table `dbo.ser_number_all` and added a uniqueidentifier column to have a primary key, which we don't have in the view above.

In Oracle I would do an insert now like this:

```
insert into [dbo].[ser_number_all]
  ( ID
  , Serialnumber
  , TypeName
  , Date
  , Parent_Serialnumber
  , JobNumber
  , ProductNode)
  select init_id_seq.nextval
          , Serialnumber
          , TypeName
          , Date
          , Parent_Serialnumber
          , JobNumber
          , ProductNode
  from dbo.Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers
where not exists (select 1
                  from Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as hv
                  where hv. Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Serialnumber
                  and hv. TypeName = ser_number_all.TypeName
                  and hv. Date = ser_number_all.Date
                  and hv. Parent_Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Parent_Serialnumber
                  and hv. JobNumber = ser_number_all.JobNumber
                  and hv. ProductNode = ser_number_all.ProductNode);
```

But SQL Server always returns an error

> The multi-part identifier init_id_seq.nextval could not be bound

and the same on all the columns in the

```
select 1 statement. "ser_number_all.Serialnumber", "ser_number_all.TypeName", "ser_number_all.Date", "ser_number_all.Parent_Serialnumber", "ser_number_all.JobNumber" and "ser_number_all.ProductNode"`.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thnx

Comment: here SQL considers 'init_id_seq' either a table name or an alias to a table name - however you have not aliased any table as init_id_seq and it is not the table you referred to in the FROM statement - what is your understanding of init_id_seq here?

Comment: in the SELECT 1 part, I think you need to select from [ser_number_all] where [ser_number_all] .Serialnumber  = Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers.SerialNumber etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
insert into [dbo].[ser_number_all]
  ( ID
  , Serialnumber
  , TypeName
  , Date
  , Parent_Serialnumber
  , JobNumber
  , ProductNode)
  select init_id_seq.nextval
      , Serialnumber
      , TypeName
      , Date
      , Parent_Serialnumber
      , JobNumber
      , ProductNode
  from dbo.Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as ser_number_all
where not exists (select 1
                  from Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as hv
              where hv. Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Serialnumber
              and hv. TypeName = ser_number_all.TypeName
              and hv. Date = ser_number_all.Date
              and hv. Parent_Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Parent_Serialnumber
              and hv. JobNumber = ser_number_all.JobNumber
              and hv. ProductNode = ser_number_all.ProductNode);
```

OR

```
    insert into [dbo].[ser_number_all]
  ( ID
  , Serialnumber
  , TypeName
  , Date
  , Parent_Serialnumber
  , JobNumber
  , ProductNode)
  select init_id_seq.nextval
      , Serialnumber
      , TypeName
      , Date
      , Parent_Serialnumber
      , JobNumber
      , ProductNode
  from dbo.Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers 
where not exists (select 1
                  from Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as hv
              where hv. Serialnumber = Serialnumber
              and hv. TypeName = TypeName
              and hv. Date = Date
              and hv. Parent_Serialnumber = Parent_Serialnumber
              and hv. JobNumber = JobNumber
              and hv. ProductNode = ProductNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

something more like the following - alias Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers to hv and check if it's value is absent from [ser_number_all]

```
    insert into [dbo].[ser_number_all]
  ( ID
   , Serialnumber
   , TypeName
   , Date
   , Parent_Serialnumber
  , JobNumber
  , ProductNode)
  select hv.nextval
          , hv.Serialnumber
          , hv.TypeName
          , hv.[Date]
          , hv.Parent_Serialnumber
          , hv.JobNumber
          , hv.ProductNode
    from dbo.Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers hv
  where not exists (select 1
                                  from[ser_number_all]  ser_number_all
                                 where hv. Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Serialnumber
                                     and hv. TypeName = ser_number_all.TypeName
                                     and hv. Date = ser_number_all.Date
                                     and hv. Parent_Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Parent_Serialnumber
                                     and hv. JobNumber = ser_number_all.JobNumber
                                     and hv. ProductNode = ser_number_all.ProductNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
insert into [dbo].[ser_number_all]
  ( ID
  , Serialnumber
  , TypeName
  , Date
  , Parent_Serialnumber
  , JobNumber
  , ProductNode)
  select init_id_seq.nextval
      , Serialnumber
      , TypeName
      , Date
      , Parent_Serialnumber
      , JobNumber
      , ProductNode
  from dbo.Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as ser_number_all
where not exists (select 1
                  from Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as hv
              where hv. Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Serialnumber
              and hv. TypeName = ser_number_all.TypeName
              and hv. Date = ser_number_all.Date
              and hv. Parent_Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Parent_Serialnumber
              and hv. JobNumber = ser_number_all.JobNumber
              and hv. ProductNode = ser_number_all.ProductNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about how Oracle handles its databases but looking at `init_id_seq.nextval` it looks like a method call that would return the next avaiable unique identity.

If that is the case you would need to handle it differently in SQL server. When setting up the identity column, in the table designer, mark the identity column as isIdentity. Remove this column from your insert statement. SQL will automatically populate it with the next seed value.

Alternatively if the field is a unique identifier and you want to include it in your insert statement you can replace `init_id_seq.nextval` with `NEWID()`

Comment: Wow, you guys are awesome!!!! I was just quickly at the dentist and back in the office I have already the solution :-)
Thank you all for your answers, I have it running now!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the same control over sequences in SQL Server as in Oracle. To insert Guids into a table, you will need to use the `NEWID()` function to accomplish the same results as `init_id_seq.nextval`.

```
insert into [dbo].[ser_number_all]
  ( ID
  , Serialnumber
  , TypeName
  , Date
  , Parent_Serialnumber
  , JobNumber
  , ProductNode)
  select NEWID()
          , Serialnumber
          , TypeName
          , Date
          , Parent_Serialnumber
          , JobNumber
          , ProductNode
  from dbo.Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers
where not exists (select 1
                  from Hierachical_View_with_Jobnumbers as hv
                  where hv. Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Serialnumber
                  and hv. TypeName = ser_number_all.TypeName
                  and hv. Date = ser_number_all.Date
                  and hv. Parent_Serialnumber = ser_number_all.Parent_Serialnumber
                  and hv. JobNumber = ser_number_all.JobNumber
                  and hv. ProductNode = ser_number_all.ProductNode);
```